# Preloader: How can I set a timeout before the script adds the loaded class?

Tags: javascript, html, indexing, preloader

I have to ask you guys, what is wrong in this code, I created a preloader for my website but I failed at the javascript:

```
    <!-- script for preloader -->
    <script type="text/javascript/jquery">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('body').addClass('loaded')
            }, 1500);
        });
    </script>

    <!-- preloader* -->
    <div id="loader-wrapper">
        <div id="loader"></div>
        <div class="loader-section section-one"></div>
        <div class="loader-section section-two"></div>
    </div>
```

So the preloader stops as soon as the `<body>` tag get the `class="loaded"`. But for some reasons the `<body>` doesn't receive the class.

I don't know if it helps, but here's the whole file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?= $view->render('head') ?>
    <link href="packages/pagekit/theme-hello/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <?php $view->script('theme', 'theme:js/theme.js') ?>
    <?php $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; if($url == "/arn_architekten/bilderbuch"): ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            html {
                background-color: #000 !important;
                background-image: none !important;
            }
        </style>
    <? endif ?>
</head>    

<body>

    <!-- Render logo or title with site URL -->
    <a href="<?= $view->url()->get() ?>">
        <?php if ($logo = $params['logo']) : ?>
            <img src="<?= $this->escape($logo) ?>" alt="">
        <?php else : ?>
            <?= $params['title'] ?>
        <?php endif ?>
    </a>

    <!-- Render widget position -->
    <?php if ($view->position()->exists('sidebar')) : ?>
        <?= $view->position('sidebar') ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- script for preloader -->
    <script type="text/javascript/jquery">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('body').addClass('loaded')
            }, 1500);
        });
    </script>

    <!-- preloader* -->
    <div id="loader-wrapper">
        <div id="loader"></div>
        <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
        <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>
    </div>        

    <!-- Render content -->
    <?= $view->render('content') ?>

    <!-- Insert code before the closing body tag  -->
    <?= $view->render('footer') ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope somebody can help me there and sorry for my bad english ^^.

Comment: "So the preloader stops as soon as the <body> tag get the class="loaded"." care to explain this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your script as below it might caused an issue

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
  }, 1500);
});

</script>
```

**Update**

Add jquery min js this is issue if you don't load jquery js `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` add this line top of the function or inside head tag

**Update 1** 
Update your head tag as below

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <?= $view->render('head') ?>
        <link href="packages/pagekit/theme-hello/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
//add below line 
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <?php $view->script('theme', 'theme:js/theme.js') ?>
        <?php $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; if($url == "/arn_architekten/bilderbuch"): ?>
            <style type="text/css">
                html {
                    background-color: #000 !important;
                    background-image: none !important;
                }
            </style>
        <? endif ?>
    </head>
```

For more info find this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hqbmw2r1/2/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at this point: `$(document).ready(function() {...}`

Comment: @Thibs glad to help you